# Score based on marks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
name    score
a       Pass 
a       Merit 
a       Fail 
b       Merit 
b       Merit 
b       Merit 
c       Pass 
c       Pass 
c       Pass 
d       Fail 
d       Fail 
d       Fail
```

I have two column studentname and their score.
i have tried it hard but cannot get through it.
if the student have two merits he is awarded as merit.
if the student have two pass he is awarded as pass
else its a fail
so the output will be like this

```
name     score
a        fail
b        merit
c        pass
d        fail
```

Comment: What result will be for next 2 strings: -a Merit and  -a Pass  ? Without -a fail

Comment: Yeah, seems a bit "unfair" to me to let student 'a' fail on a 'pass' and a 'merit'. Isn't that better than two passes?

Comment: Yep. And I think Mukesh said about "two" only for example.... I think - need to analize all values.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a group of rows per `(name)`.  Then you can count the different types of score for each group:

```
select  name
,       case
        when count(case when score = 'merit' then 1 end) >= 2 then 'merit'
        when count(case when score = 'pass' then 1 end) >= 2 then 'pass'
        else 'fail'
        end
from    YourTable
group by
        name
```

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7d3a/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

A little "fairer" IMHO would be to apply the following:

```
select  name, count(case when score = 'merit' then 1 end) merits,
        count(case when score = 'pass' then 1 end) passes,
        count(case when score in ('merit','pass') then 1 end) meritsORpasses,
        case
         when count(case when score = 'merit' then 1 end) >= 2 then 'merit'
         when count(case when score in ('merit','pass') then 1 end) >= 2 then 'pass'
         else 'fail'
        end decision
from    tbl group by name
```

with this result:

```
name    merits  passes  meritsORpasses  decision
a       1       1       2               pass
b       3       0       3               merit
c       0       3       3               pass
d       0       0       0               fail
```

You can of course leave out the columns `merits, passes` and `meritsORpasses`. I only put them in for illustration.

Using Andomar's fiddle, here is a [working version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7d3a/3)